# How to iterate a column in QTableWidget and check if a check box is checked?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

How can I iterate one column in `QTableWidget` and check if a checkbox is checked?

[image]

When I clicked the button in the left, I want to iterate the column in the picture and check if a checkbox is checked.

As of now, I've tried this function but the function only return `None`:

```py
def checkBoxcheck(self):
    print("checkBoxcheck started")
    for row in range(self.rowCount()):
        print(self.cellWidget(1, 1))
        if not self.cellWidget(1, 1) is None:
            if self.cellWidget(row, 1).isChecked():
                #others to do
```

This is the code to use in order to reproduce this problem (I already removed those unnecessary parts of the code):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QTableWidget, \
                        QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys

class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(10, 3)
        self.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(10)
        self.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(200)

        for rows in range(self.rowCount()):
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.setItem(rows, 1, item)

    def checkBoxcheck(self):
        print("checkBoxcheck started")
        for row in range(self.rowCount()):
            print(self.cellWidget(1, 1))
            if not self.cellWidget(1, 1) is None:
                if self.cellWidget(row, 1).isChecked():
                    #others to do
                    pass


class AppDemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(700, 500)

        mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        table = TableWidget()
        mainLayout.addWidget(table)
        buttonLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        button_new = QPushButton('Check if checked')
        button_new.clicked.connect(table.checkBoxcheck)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(button_new)

        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonLayout)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

def app():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = AppDemo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

app()
```

I hope you can help me with this problem

Comment: Just for clarity, besides the explanation in my answer, in your loop you're always checking the item at `(1, 1)`, which is clearly pointless.

Comment: Ok, I just noticed that it *was* a typo, that you repeated *again*, and that you already posted another question. So: 1. Please be more careful in using variables of for loops; 2. Follow the suggestions given to you more carefully; 3. Don't create new questions if you just need to add details or code, use the [edit] link and modify the post instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "cell widget" is a QWidget that is added to an index of the view, as much as it's done using [`setIndexWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget) for any QAbstractItemView. It can be *any* widget, a checkbox, a combo, a custom widget, or even *another* item view.

If the requirement is to have checkable items, there's no need for that, since Qt models already provide the feature, which you're already using when doing `item.setCheckState()`.

So, the solution is much simpler: look for the `item()`, and then verify the state:

```
for row in range(self.rowCount()):
    item = self.item(row, 1)
    if item is not None and item.checkState():
        # ...
```

Remember that:

- QTableWidget can have *empty* cells, which are items for which no QTableWidgetItem has been set yet and no data has been inserted by the user (even if their index exist), that's why I had to check if the item is not None;
- don't confuse `item(row, col)` with [`itemAt(x, y)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#itemAt-1), which is based on pixel coordinates on the view;
- if an item has no `checkState` explicitly set, its value is also `None`.
- don't use booleans to set and verify the states, because [Qt check states](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#CheckState-enum) are *tristate*: `Unchecked` (0), `PartiallyChecked` (1) and `Checked` (2); by default their mouse behavior *is* boolean, but you have to consiser this before doing any "basic" action like you'd do with a basic `bool` (for QCheckBox, though, as for any button, you can use `isChecked()` and `setChecked()`, which are normal boolean based functions); this means that if you try to do `setCheckState(True)`, the result will be a ***partially checked*** item, since for python `True` is the same as `1` (so, in Qt terms, `PartiallyChecked`): if you want to set a *fully* checked state, you *should* to do `setCheckState(Qt.Checked)`;

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, I'm really sorry about asking a duplicate of my other question but I will make sure that it will never happen again.

Comment: Couldn't they do an `is True` check to distinguish between boolean and integer? That's just asking for errors.

Comment: @PatrickParker 1. You have to remember that PyQt is a *binding*, a system that allows to use Qt (which is written in C++ and compiled) from Python; 2. The PyQt maintainer puts lots of efforts in keeping the "mid-level-API" as much consistent as possible with the original API; 3. The `Qt.CheckState` is tristate by design, providing an intermediate check would mean to create performance issues; 4. if you don't like the default behavior, just subclass and override `setData` by checking the `Qt.CheckStateRole`.